# Display the most recent entry of duplicates based on the Date Column of a DataTable

Tags: vb.net, winforms, linq, date, datagridview

I have data table with Columns: `ID`, `Chapter Number`, `Query ID` and `Date`".
I have duplicate questions with same `Query ID` but different dates.
I want to show, in a DataGridView, only the question (a Row) with the most recent Date when the `Query ID` is the same.
I also want to display questions (rows) which have not duplicate `Query ID`s.

My table is like this:

| ID | Chapter Number | Query ID | Date (DD-MM-YYYY) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chapter-3 | Q-03-05 | 04-05-2021 |
| 2 | Chapter-3 | Q-03-05 | 05-05-2021 |
| 3 | Chapter-3 | Q-03-04 | 06-05-2021 |
| 4 | Chapter-3 | Q-03-06 | 07-05-2021 |

I want the table entries in DataGridView like this:

| ID | Chapter Number | Query ID | Date (DD-MM-YYYY) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Chapter-3 | Q-03-05 | 05-05-2021 |
| 3 | Chapter-3 | Q-03-04 | 06-05-2021 |
| 4 | Chapter-3 | Q-03-06 | 07-05-2021 |

Here is my code:

```
Dim duplicates = 
   (From cust In SARDataSet.Table1
    Group By dupp = cust.Query_ID Into GP = Group
    Order By dupp Ascending
    Select GP).First()

For Each dw In duplicates
    DataGridView3.DataSource = duplicates.ToList()
Next
```

Answer (score 2):

You're ordering the result based on the Group, you should order in descending order using the Column that stores the `Date` objects, then take the first one.
Then the loop tries to set the results cast to a List multiple times. You clearly don't want that.

Assuming the Column is actually storing dates and not strings.
If you stored strings, change the Column Type to `DateTime` (`Date`), otherwise ordering this Column won't ever achieve the desired results.

Add a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtension` in the unfortunate case you don't have it already in your Project. I'm naming the Date Type Column `QueryDate` since I don't know its actual name.

Here, I'm generating a new DataTable that contains the filtered results and set it as the DataSource of your DataGridView:

```
Dim dtNew = SARDataSet.Table1.AsEnumerable().
    GroupBy(Function(dr) dr("Query ID")).
    Select(Function(grp) 
        grp.OrderByDescending(Function(dr) dr("QueryDate")).First()).
    CopyToDataTable()

' In case a source of data is already assigned
DataGridView3.DataSource = Nothing
' Set the new data
DataGridView3.DataSource = dtNew
```

---

What the LINQ code is doing:

- `AsEnumerable()`: reads a DataTable as a collection of DataRows objects
- `GroupBy()` => `dr("Query_ID")`: Groups the DataRows objects based on the value of the `Query_ID` Column
- `Select(Function(grp)`: enumerates the generated Groups and...
- `grp.OrderByDescending(Function(dr) dr("QueryDate"))` ...orders the DataRows in each Group by the *Date* Column in descending order (most recent Date first) then...
- `First()`: ...takes the first DataRow in the ordered list
- `CopyToDataTable()`: converts the resulting `IEnumerable(Of DataRow)` to a new DataTable object.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your good suggestion. I have tried this code and giving error; System.ArgumentException: 'Column 'Query_ID' does not belong to table Table1.' While 'Query_ID' exist in Table1. Please guide me.

Comment: Don't you know what are the names of those Columns? Set a breakpoint in the first line of this code and inspect the DataTable's Columns to see what their names are, then replace the name used here with the real ones. That's all.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. I have changed Query_ID to "Query ID" Now it is working

Comment: Thanks Mr. Jimi for you kind suggestions.